# iOS programmatically created UIButton action stops working after from 3rd UIView onwards

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

I created a cool app that programmatically creates over 50+ `UIButtons` including an action selector.
The action (playing a sound) stops working from the 3rd `UIView` onwards.

The `UIView` is inside the `UIScrollView` and uses paging.

I use iOS 5, but I don't think that is the issue.
Also the sound works fine on the first and second page in the `UIScrollView`.
Also if I change the amount of buttons (more or less) the sound always works as a charm,
till I reach the 3rd page :/

Here the code:

```
- (void)setButtons
{
    int screenWidth = 320;
    int screenHeight = 410;

    int rows = krows;
    int cols = kcols;
    int marginLeft = kmarginLeft;
    int height = kheight;
    int buttonWidth = kbuttonWidth;
    int buttonHeight = kbuttonHeight;
    int delta = kdelta; // gap between buttons
    int startPosY = kstartPosY; 
    int startPosX = kstartPosX;
    int posY = startPosY;
    int posX = startPosX;
    int contentWidth = screenWidth;
    int intStart = 0;

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [Persistence getDictFromParam:@"Bud"];
    NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];

    // sort keys 
    NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    int len = keys.count; //50;
    NSLog(@"len: %d", len);

    CGSize scrollViewContentSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth, screenHeight);
    [scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewContentSize];

    for( int i = intStart; i < len; i++ ) {
        UIButton* aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sound1Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        NSString *key = [sortedKeys objectAtIndex:i];

        if (i > 0) {
            posY += delta + height;

            int mod = i % rows;
            if(mod == 0) {
                int mod2 = i % (rows*cols);
                if(mod2 == 0) {
                    posX += marginLeft;
                }
                posX += (marginLeft + buttonWidth);

                // extend pages
                if(posX > contentWidth) {
                    contentWidth += screenWidth;
                    CGSize scrollViewContentSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth, screenHeight);
                    [scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewContentSize];
                }
                posY = startPosY;
            }
        }

        [aButton setFrame:CGRectMake(posX, posY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
        NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", key];

        [aButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_pushed.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [aButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_pushed.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [aButton setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [aButton setTag:i];
        NSLog(@"%@: %d",title, aButton.tag);
        [contentView addSubview:aButton];
    }

    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
}


- (void)sound1Action:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    int i = button.tag;
    BackgroundMusic *backgroundMusic = [BackgroundMusic sharedInstance];

    NSArray *sortedKeys = [self sortedDict];
    NSString *val = [[self getDict] objectForKey:[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog(@"%@",val);

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:val withExtension:nil];
    NSString *pathUrl = [url path];

    backgroundMusic.player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathUrl] error:NULL]; 

    [backgroundMusic.player stop];
    [backgroundMusic.player play];

    [backgroundMusic player].volume = 0.5;
    backgroundMusic.player.numberOfLoops = 0; //-1; initite
}
```

Comment: if your buttons are displayed as desired and the issue is that sound is not being played, maybe you should attach source of `sound1Action` method as well

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints in your code and stepping through to find what is and isn't being called, if any values are nil, etc? It's surprising how few people actually use the tools given to them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I tried the breakpoints and it is not called after I slide to the 3rd screen.

Comment: I added the sound1Action now as well.

Comment: In `sound1Action`, did you check if `NSLog(@"%@",val);` gives the right value on the 3rd page? Or is `sound1Action` not being called at all on 3rd page?

Comment: It is not being called at all on the 3rd page.

Comment: Does the sound1Action method actually get called when you press a button on page 3?

Comment: If found the issue guys. I had to extend also the contentView where the buttons are assigned too. If I extend the frame as well, then it works perfectly.